# Existence of adjacent $a, b$ in a general bipartite graph (with a special degree condition) such that $\frac{\deg(a)}{\deg(b)} \ge \frac{|B|}{|A|}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Suppose a bipartite graph with two parts $A, B$, for every $b \in B$ we know $\deg(b) \ge 1$.

Prove there exists an adjacent $a \in A, b \in B$ such that $\frac{\deg(a)}{\deg(b)} \ge \frac{|B|}{|A|}$.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay No this is just a problem from one of my exams and I just try to upsolve it.

Comment: Maybe a pigeonhole type of argument?

Comment: This is well known when $|A|=|B|$, and the same trick works for your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let each vertex $b\in B$ have a can of jam of weight 1, and share it with all neighbours from $A$ equally. There should be a vertex $a\in A$ which got at least $|B|/|A|$ of jam, she got at least $|B|/(\deg(a) \cdot |A|)$ of jam from certain vertex $b$. This pair works.

Comment: When I mention this version of double counting, I'm often met with disbelief. There are generalizations to more than two sets.